# Trying to sum where multiple instances of an account number in a month

Tags: excel, sum, frequency

I have a data sheet that `col A` is an account number, `col F` is a payment amount, `col I` is a user, and `col H` is a payment date....I am trying to sum payment amounts that fall in the same month for a particular user for a average monthly payment amount.  It is a list of future payments that can have weekly or biweekly payments.  I am trying to find which payments fall within the same month and sum those amounts and then average those payment amounts??? Any clues?  This formula gets me a unique value for each user but cannot seem to get what I am looking for:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF('RD-CRC Payments'!I:I <> " ",IF('RD-CRC Payments'!I:I=C5,'RD-CRC Payments'!A:A)),'RD-CRC Payments'!A:A)>0))
```

Comment: Try SUMIF https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 0):

This maybe what you are looking for. Enter cell with Name and cell with Date/Month you want to search for where it says CELLWITHDATE and CELLWITHNAME.

This will get you the sum.

```
=SUMIFS('RD-CRC Payments'!F:F,'RD-CRC Payments'!H:H,">="&EOMONTH(CELLWITHDATE,-1)+1,'RD-CRC Payments'!H:H,"<="&EOMONTH(CELLWITHDATE,0),'RD-CRC Payments'!I:I,CELLWITHNAME)
```

This will get you the average payment for that month.

```
=SUMIFS('RD-CRC Payments'!F:F,'RD-CRC Payments'!H:H,">="&EOMONTH(CELLWITHDATE,-1)+1,'RD-CRC Payments'!H:H,"<="&EOMONTH(CELLWITHDATE,0),'RD-CRC Payments'!I:I,CELLWITHNAME)/COUNTIFS('RD-CRC Payments'!H:H,">="&EOMONTH(CELLWITHDATE,-1)+1,'RD-CRC Payments'!H:H,"<="&EOMONTH(CELLWITHDATE,0),'RD-CRC Payments'!I:I,CELLWITHNAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add this if you need to use a Month instead of an Actual Date. This can be adjusted to use over years as well.

```
=SUMIFS($F:$F,$H:$H,">="&DATEVALUE(CellWithMonth&" 1"),$H:$H,"<="&EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(CellWithMonth&" 1"),0),$I:$I,CellWithName)

=SUMIFS($F:$F,$H:$H,">="&EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(CellWithMonth&" 1"),-1)+1,$H:$H,"<="&EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(CellWithMonth&" 1"),0),$I:$I,CellWithName)/COUNTIFS($H:$H,">="&EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(CellWithMonth&" 1"),-1)+1,$H:$H,"<="&EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(CellWithMonth&" 1"),0),$I:$I,CellWithName)
```